# Waking Android device from sleep mode

Tags: android, android-service

Is it possible to make an app to wake up android device from sleep mode by saying a particular word?

I came across [this](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Android-4.4-may-bring-always-listening-Google-Now_id48271) post which says it depends on the processor and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206379/android-listen-for-a-voice-command-all-the-time) post which has the same question but with no answer but the youtube link in it shows an app which does it, but how?

Basically the service which we implement to run at background should keep running even when phone gets into the sleep mode.

How can we create a service like that?

Any help on this will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)